# How can we emulate variadic templates in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In C++ we can define a function which takes a variable number of statically typed arguments, using [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), like so:

```
template<typename... Params> void f(Params... parameters);
```

(Alternatively we could have create a struct with variadic number of fields and used that as the argument to `f`.)

We can also use type traits to inspect the values. I would like to do something similar in Haskell.

I'd like to define a data type and a family of functions with a parameterized number of statically typed arguments:

```
data T ??? = ...
mkT :: ... -> T ???
f :: T ??? -> ...
```

`f` needs to be able to convert the parameter types to *values* so we can do something generic with them (think printf).

Perhaps a job for HLists?

Comment: Do you want to do anything that requires `T` to be something other than simply `HList`? I ask this because even If you need to filter or manipulate the type list, you can do that separately from the data definition, and put the resulting types in a HList all the same.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me yet what you need. To encode variadic functions in Haskell, you can use overloading (as the `quickCheck` function does) , continuations, often embedded in datatypes (see e.g. `formatting` on Hackage), HList and combinations of these.  Without a concrete use case, it is difficult to say what is best.

Comment: @AndrásKovács `T` will probably contains a map, keyed by the type parameter, to some record.